# how to resolve HTTP 500 error in uploadify in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, uploadify

when i am using uploadify without hosting in iis ,it's working but in IIS it's not working
i am getting below error message 
**http 500 error**

my uplodify contain likw

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=file_upload.ClientID %>").uploadify({
            'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': 'Handler.ashx',
            'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Select Files',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,


            'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {

                alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);

            },

            'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {

                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Upload.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                    data: "{ sendData: 'ok' }",
                    success: function (result) {

                       alert(result.d);

                    }
                })
            }
        });
    })


//    $("#<%=ddlPageName.ClientID %>").change(function () {
//        alert("hi");
//        var Pnamespace = $('#<%=ddlCustomerName.ClientID %> option:selected').attr('value');
//        $("#<%=hnpagenamespace.ClientID %>").attr('value', Pnamespace);
//    });
    </script>
```

below ServerSideMethod method in upload.aspx page

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]

      public static string ServerSideMethod()
    {
        string strSend = string.Empty;

       strsend="hi";


        }
        return strSend;
      }
```

Comment: Can you attach the remote debugger?  That will help immensely in these situations.

Comment: how to attach remote debugger?

Comment: Do some googling for Visual Studio Remote Debugger.  Essentially there's an executable and some libraries that you copy to the target server, run the executable, and connect using visual studio's Debug > Attach to Process.  You enter the target server name, and select the w3wp.exe process that is running your application (hint: it may not be started until you go to the website).

Comment: i have added but pls let me know how to track actual problem??

Comment: Check Windows Application Event Viewer on the server - any warning (yellow exclamation points) related to ASP.NET - what does it say?

Comment: Simply attach to the w3wp.exe process on the remote server, allow the debugger to get going, and reproduce the error.  It should show the exception where it occurs.

Comment: thanks all.i found my issue by below artical
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/12/iis7-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is.html

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be the "return strSend;" inside your "ServerSideMethod()" function? Because in your example it's outside the method..